prometheus-net library doesn't publish exemplars, i'm using docs code
prometheus-net docs show us how to use exemplars this way:
var exemplar = Exemplar.From(Exemplar.Pair("traceID", "1234"));
        
// Determine the winner and report the change in score.
if (googleStopwatch.Elapsed < microsoftStopwatch.Elapsed)
{
    WinsByEndpoint.WithLabels(googleUrl).Inc(exemplar);
    LossesByEndpoint.WithLabels(microsoftUrl).Inc(exemplar);
}

but this code throws runtime exception as exemplar object can only be used for one metric(so you should .Clone() it). I simplified doc's code to just
var exemplar1 = Exemplar.FromTraceContext(); // it isn't null here, i debugged. also tried to try doc's Exemplar.From(Exemplar.Pair("traceID", "1234")), same happens

// Determine the winner and report the change in score.
if (googleStopwatch.Elapsed < microsoftStopwatch.Elapsed)
{
    WinsByEndpoint.WithLabels(googleUrl).Inc();
    LossesByEndpoint.WithLabels(microsoftUrl).Inc();
}
else if (googleStopwatch.Elapsed > microsoftStopwatch.Elapsed)
{
    WinsByEndpoint.WithLabels(microsoftUrl).Inc();
    LossesByEndpoint.WithLabels(googleUrl).Inc();
}
else
{
    // It's a draw! No winner.
}

// Report the difference.
var difference = Math.Abs(googleStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds - microsoftStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
Difference.Observe(difference, exemplar: exemplar1);

so now it only publishes exemplar in the Difference metric. But it just doesn't.
# HELP sampleservice_difference_seconds How far apart the winner and loser were, in seconds.
# TYPE sampleservice_difference_seconds histogram
sampleservice_difference_seconds_sum 11.822541600000001
sampleservice_difference_seconds_count 3
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.01"} 0
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.02"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.03"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.04"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.05"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.06"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.07"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.08"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.09"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.1"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.2"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.3"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.4"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.5"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.6"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.7"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.8"} 1
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="0.9"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="1"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="2"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="3"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="4"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="5"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="6"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="7"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="8"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="9"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="10"} 2
sampleservice_difference_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf"} 3

my code follows all the methods from the docs, but it doesn't publish exemplars. did anyone encounter this behaviour?
source code: https://github.com/usersuseruuseruser/EffectiveMobile/tree/master/EffectiveMobile
i
